# Set font color, font style and background color to ListView.Item.Caption

Tags: delphi, listviewitem

How to set font color, font style and background color to `ListView.Item.Caption`? My code, as you can see on image below, is not working.

[image]

```
procedure TFMainForm.ListView1CustomDrawSubItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; SubItem: Integer; State: TCustomDrawState;
  var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  case SubItem of
    0:
      begin
        Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clLime;
        Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
        Sender.Canvas.Font.Style := [FsBOld];
      end;
    1:
      begin
        Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clLime;
        Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
        Sender.Canvas.Font.Style := [FsBOld];
      end;
    2:
      begin
        Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
        Sender.Canvas.Font.Style := [FsBOld];
      end;
    3:
      begin
        Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
        Sender.Canvas.Font.Style := [FsBOld];
      end;
    4:
      begin
        Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
        Sender.Canvas.Font.Style := [FsBOld];
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OnCustomDrawSubItem()` draws only subitems. Use `OnCustomDrawItem()` to draw the items.

```
procedure TForm24.ListView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clLime;
end;

procedure TForm24.ListView1CustomDrawSubItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; SubItem: Integer; State: TCustomDrawState;
  var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow;
end;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

And this is how you color a single Subitem cell:
(in my case the data of subitem Nr 4 has to be above zero, and the Subitem must be Nr 5. After each cell draw you have to set the color to clblack again.

```
procedure TfrmCandlebot.ListView2CustomDrawSubItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; SubItem: Integer; State: TCustomDrawState;
  var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  if ((StrToInt(Item.SubItems[4]) >  0) and (Subitem=5)) then Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color:= clWebLimeGreen ;
  if ((StrToInt(Item.SubItems[4]) <  0) and (Subitem=5)) then Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color:= clWebOrangeRed;
  Sender.Canvas.Font.Color:= clblack;

end;
```

[Picture with listview and colored cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkmSG.png)